# Spped up MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need help speeding up a MySQL query that's running extremely slowly.  It's taking over 35 seconds to return 900 rows.

Does anyone have ideas how I can speed things up on this query?

Many thanks in advance

```
select products.*, 
p.price as lowest_price, 
products_images.thumbnail 
from products 
    inner join products_categories on products_categories.product_id = products.id 
    inner join products_colours on products_colours.product_id = products.id 
    inner join products_quantity_pricing on products_quantity_pricing.product_id = products.id 
    left join ( select min(price) as price, product_id from products_quantity_pricing group by products_quantity_pricing.product_id ) as p on p.product_id = products.id 
    inner join products_images on products_images.product_id = products.id 
where products.id > 0 group by products.id 
order by products.product_name
```

Here is the setup of the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` smallint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1016 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
   `product_prefix` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `id` smallint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_product_code` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `product_description` text NOT NULL,
  `print_area` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `print_position` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dimensions` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origination` tinytext,
  `unit_cost` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_code` (`product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=901 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` smallint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `fullsize` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `midsize` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `colour_tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2402 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_colours` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` smallint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `colour` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2546 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_quantity_pricing` (
  `product_id` smallint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on the `product_id` columns in all the tables.

In the `products_quantity_pricing`, a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on `(product_id, price)` will also speed up finding the minimum price for each product. If you create this composite index, you don't need to create a separate index just on `product_id`; the prefix of a composite index also serves as an index of its own.

Comment: In order to create the composite index, would this work: CREATE INDEX min_price ON products_quantity_pricing (product_id, price);

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax.